# Script exceeds maximum execution time

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using a script to first copy a list of all terminated products from "data" tab of the sheet to the "terminated tab"

The data tab looks like below

[image]

The code checks if there is an end date written 
if it is - the row is copied and pasted in the "terminated" tab

Once all rows (around 2000) are completed

the code the deletes all rows from the "data" tab that have an end date on it

But  the code is not very efficient and data is huge - I get a "maximum execution time exceeded" error

```
function movingTerms() {
  var app = SpreadsheetApp ;
  var sheet1 =  app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("data") ;
  var sheet3 = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Terminations");

  var range1 = sheet1.getRange(2, 1, sheet1.getLastRow() - 1,9);
  var range3 = sheet3.getRange(2, 1, sheet3.getLastRow(), 9);

  var values1 = range1.getValues();
  var values3 = range3.getValues();
  var rowcount = sheet1.getLastRow();
  var row_deleted = 0; 

  for (var i = 0; i < (sheet1.getLastRow() - 1); i++) 
  {
    if (values1[i][4] !== "")     
    {
      var rowtodelete = sheet1.getRange(i + 2, 1, 1, 10);
      var rowtoadd = sheet3.getRange(sheet3.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
      rowtodelete.copyTo(rowtoadd);
    }
  }   

  for (var k = 0; k < values1.length; k++)
  {
    var row = k + 1 - row_deleted; 
    if (values1[k][4] !== "")       
    {
      var getridof  = row +1;
      sheet1.deleteRow(getridof);
      row_deleted++;
    } 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I generally like to see the spreadsheet to do this correctly but this is the way that I would do it.

```
function movingTerms() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet1=ss.getSheetByName("data") ;
  var sheet3=ss.getSheetByName("Terminations");
  var range1=sheet1.getRange(2, 1, sheet1.getLastRow()-1,9);
  var range3=sheet3.getRange(2, 1, sheet3.getLastRow(),9);//You don't really need this
  var values1=range1.getValues();
  var values3=range3.getValues();//You don't really need this
  var rowcount=sheet1.getLastRow();
  var rowsdeleted = 0; 
  for (var i=0;i<values1.length;i++) {
    if (values1[i][4]!="") {//column5
      var rowtodelete = sheet1.getRange(i-rowsdeleted+2, 1, 1, 10);
      var rowtoadd = sheet3.getRange(sheet3.getLastRow()+1,1);//You could also append to sheet 3 if you wish
      rowtodelete.copyTo(rowtoadd);
      sheet1.deleteRow(i-rowsdeleted+2);
      rowsdeleted++;
    }
  }
}
```